# the method save changes are failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the post method which creates a new cream

```
public ActionResult CreateCream(CreamModel cream, string creamTypeId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (creamTypeId != string.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    cream.CreamTypeModel_id = int.Parse(creamTypeId);
                    creamManager.CreateCream(cream);
                    TempData["message"] = string.Format("Игрок {0} сохранен", cream.Name);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ChoosingCreamType = GetCreamSelectList();
        return View(cream);
    }
```

when I call

```
public void CreateCream(CreamModel newCream)
    {
        if (newCream.Id == 0)
        {
            context.CreamModels.Add(newCream);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

when I call `context.SaveChanges()` the code fails and I go to `View`, instead of  `redirect`! I don't understand why it doesn't work? If i delete `SaveChanges()` it executes, but doesn't save in database.

my model

```
public class CreamModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    public int? CreamTypeModel_id { get; set; }
    public CreamTypeModel CreamTypeModel { get; set; }
}
```

error message

> SqlException: The column name 'CreamTypeModel_id' is specified more
>   than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column
>   cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the
>   clause to make sure that a column is updated only once.  If this
>   statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can
>   conceal the duplication in your code.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: How does it fail? What's the error?

Comment: `when I call context.SaveChanges() the code are failed and I always go to View`-That means that your model data is invalid.

Comment: TanvirArjel  - but why? I don't use data annotation and make any validation, and a have almost 1 problem with decimal because i take native validation error(`The value '1.22' is not valid for Price.` and `The field Price must be a number.`), i can't write dot or comma, but I actually use integer. and other problem I dont know.

Comment: what is the output of `Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);` ?

Comment: Analyze the `ModelState` under a debugger, it should tell you the problem.

Comment: This is a separate point, but why are you sending creamTypeId in a separate parameter to the action method, when CreamTypeModel_id (which you later assign that value to) is already part of the model? That doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: It doesn't seems like you know how to properly send your model datas to a function. Or the database isn't exactly like you think it is.

Comment: **ADyson** - Because i choose by DropDownList in view the type(it return string id), and after this I parse and write it to model.

 **Antoine Pelletier** - if it's need i can show the database data

**tschmit007** -An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details

Comment: Maybe `id` is a primary key, and you are trying to insert a new record with duplicate `id`?

Comment: I add the error message in my question

Comment: Can you check CreamTypeModel, seems something wrong there? and better create CreamTypeModel virtual for lazy loading purpose.

Comment: "Because i choose by DropDownList in view the type(it return string id), and after this I parse and write it to model." so why not assign it directly to the model within the view? That's the whole point of model binding

Comment: Instead of giving your dropdownlist the name "creamTypeId" you just give it the name "CreamTypeModel_id" and it will write the value directly to the model, same as your other fields.

Comment: You should enable logging and check the generated sql: `context.Database.Log = x => Console.WriteLine(x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that comes to mind is that you have a relationship without associating the FK:

```
public class CreamModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreamTypeModel")] 
    public int? CreamTypeModel_id { get; set; }
    public virtual CreamTypeModel CreamTypeModel { get; set; }
}
```

This links up the FK to the associated reference property.